# Pygame Sprite Class not working

Tags: python, pygame

```
    bg = "lv1.jpg"
    ch = "char.png"

    import pygame, sys
    from pygame.locals import *

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 400), 0, 32)
    background = pygame.image.load(bg).convert()
    char = pygame.image.load(ch).convert_alpha()


    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    charspeed = 0

    charx = 100
    chary = 200

    running = True

    class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


        def __init__(self):

            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)


            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        def blit(self):
            screen.blit(char, (100,400))

    while running:

        milli = clock.tick()
        seconds = milli/1000.
        chardm = seconds*charspeed 
        charx += chardm



        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()



        screen.blit(background, (0,0))

        player1 = Player()
        player1.blit()

        pygame.display.update()
```

For some reason the Sprite class "Player" doesn't want to work. I never got how sprites work. They are very complicated to me. I am very new to PyGame so can someone please give me a brief explanation on how sprites work and how to make and use sprite classes.

Comment: What do you mean by *the Sprite class "Player" doesn't want to work*?

Comment: @ZenOfPython it doesn't want to blit out the image char.png

Comment: No offence intended, but it looks like you're trying to jump ahead too far based on your current knowledge. Classes in Python *are* hard to get your head around when you're starting. I'd suggest stepping back a bit, and maybe going over some tutorials like [this one](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

will crash because the class `Player` does not have an attribute called `image`.

If you want to use pygame's `Sprite` class, you should follow its [documentation](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and add an `image` and an `rect` attribue:

> The base class for visible game objects. Derived classes will want to override the Sprite.update() and assign a Sprite.image and Sprite.rect attributes. The initializer can accept any number of Group instances to be added to.

The benefit of using pygame's `Sprite` class is that you can easily manage your sprite using the `Group` class and its subclasses.

So, create a `Group`:

```
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

Add your player to this group and create an `image` attribute:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, sprites)
        self.image = char
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(left=100, top=100)
```

Also, only create a single instance of the `Player` class instead of one every iteration of your main loop, and simply call `sprites.draw` to draw all sprites at once:

```
...
player1 = Player()

while running:
    ...
    sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Should not you add the sprite to your sprite Group before drawing it?

Comment: @AnuranBarman You can pass `Groups` to Sprite's `__init__` function and it will add itself to all those. Look at this line: `pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, sprites)`